# Combine several hotkeys into hotstring

Tags: autohotkey

I know about hotstrings:

```
; If I press `d` key three times, there should be inserted current date and time

:*:ddd::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm
SendInput, %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

What I want is to replicate it for hotkeys, i.e. combine several hotkeys into hotstring.

This is simple hotkey:

```
+Home::
SendInput, Foo
return
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
; Press `Shift-Home` twice to send `Bar`

:*:+Home+Home::
SendInput, Bar
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SetTimer-Example #3](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples)
or use this:

```
+Home::
count++    ; for each press, increment a counter
If (count=1)
    SetTimer send_text, -500
return

send_text:
KeyWait, Shift, L
If (count=1)
    SendInput, one
If (count=2)
    SendInput, two
If (count=3)
    SendInput, three
; ...
count:=0      ; reset counter
return
```